# Implementing logging and retry mechanism in netsuite suitescripts

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am in need of a way to implement the error logging and providing a way to the admins to rtry any failure that occurs within a suitescript.

Here are my thoughts on the implementation:

Lets say for restlet i can log the datain, or the incoming data in any userevent script in a text file along with its status as success or failure. Later have a scheduled script to process that text file that may send those errors to my .Net Api and I can provide a way for Admins to retry.

Could anyone suggest me how its normally done in netsuite projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For similar systems, I typically advise you create Custom Records. Your custom records can have a field to store the raw data (JSON, xml, etc) as well as a Status (Succeeded, Failed, Retry, etc). You could consider retry mechanisms like having a User Event on the Custom Record that immediately retries upon creation of the record, then if that fails have a Map/Reduce that runs on a regular schedule to clean things up.

If the native Execution Logs aren't providing enough functionality for you in that respect, you can add a Custom Record for "logging" as well, but I'd suggest trying to use the native logs first. The Script Execution Logs UI provides reasonable searching/filtering capabilities.